# QML GridLayout span

Tags: layout, qml

How can I make the magenta rectangle to become 6 times shorter than the red rectangle?

```
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
        Rectangle {color: "magenta"
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            color: "red"
            Layout.rowSpan: 6
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHfmB.gif

Answer (score 1):

The `Layout.fillHeight` is the problem; it tries to be as tall as possible. Instead, set `Layout.preferredHeight` to the desired height for the first column. Also, it is not necessary to change the flow when you specify the row and column for each `Rectangle` -- use `Layout.alignment` to fill from the top:

```
GridLayout {
    id: gridLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
        Layout.row: 0
        Layout.column: 0
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height/6
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
        color: "magenta"
    }
    Rectangle {
        Layout.row: 0
        Layout.column: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        color: "red"
    }
}
```