# How can I create a QML GridLayout with items of proportionate sizes?

Tags: qt, qml

Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30860285/3363018

I've been trying to create a QML layout with items that span variable numbers of rows and columns. So, e.g., a rectangle that spans two rows and four columns, one to the right of it that spans one row and two columns, and one underneath that spans three rows and five columns. A generic attempt at creating this is below:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello, World")

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        columns: 5
        rows: 2

        Rectangle {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 2

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.column: 4
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 2

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            color: "green"
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.columnSpan: 5
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 3

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

which results in this:

[image: Attempt at weighted grid layout]

As you can see, `Layout.rowSpan` and `Layout.columnSpan` don't seem to be working. Instead, the top two rows seem to take up 1:1 rather than 4:1, and the top part vs the bottom part are 1:1 rather than 2:3. I suspect this is related to `Layout.fillHeight` and `Layout.fillWidth`. [The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#fillWidth-attached-prop) states:

> If this property is **true**, the item will be as wide as possible while
> respecting the given constraints.

But, I'm not sure what "*the given constraints*" are in this context. I had hoped it would include the row and column span but it seems not.

I could probably directly calculate the item widths and heights (or maybe `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight`) but that would seem to make `Layout.rowSpan` and `Layout.columnSpan` completely superfluous. Is there a way to automatically calculate the heights based on grid rows and columns?

Comment: There is an error in the declaration: the number of rows should be 5, not 2. This does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same problem as you did but I think it's easy to misunderstand what the GridLayout is doing. If you have a grid with 5 columns and 2 rows, you get something like this, where each **O** represents a cell:

```
grid
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

`rowSpan` determines how **TALL** an object is, `columnSpan` determines how **WIDE** an object is.

You are wanting to fit these in this grid:

```
r1      r2     r3
OOOO    OO   OOOOO
OOOO         OOOOO
             OOOOO
```

You can easily see that they won't fit.

This was my solution to a 12x12 grid and should be easy to follow. `GridLayout` doesn't seem to automatically know what width and height to assign to its children, but that's okay, you can define that easily. Essentially, I'm passing in the rectangles to `Layout.columnSpan:2` and `Layout.rowSpan:2`, respectively. You could pass `rowSpan` or `columnSpan`, but I prefer this way because then I don't have to remember which function takes what:

```
GridLayout {
    id: grid
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 12
    columns: 12
    property double colMulti: grid.width / grid.columns
    property double rowMulti: grid.height / grid.rows
    function prefWidth(item){
        return colMulti * item.Layout.columnSpan
    }
    function prefHeight(item){
        return rowMulti * item.Layout.rowSpan
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: 'red'
        Layout.rowSpan: 10
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.preferredWidth: grid.prefWidth(this)
        Layout.preferredHeight: grid.prefHeight(this)
    }
    Rectangle {
        color: 'yellow'
        Layout.rowSpan: 10
        Layout.columnSpan: 10
        Layout.preferredWidth: grid.prefWidth(this)
        Layout.preferredHeight: grid.prefHeight(this)
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: greenRect
        color: 'green'
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.columnSpan: 12
        Layout.preferredWidth: grid.prefWidth(this)
        Layout.preferredHeight: grid.prefHeight(this)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: QML Grid Layout]

Answer (score 2):

Description for top-right rect has rows and columns transposed. Should be:

> one to the right of it that spans one *column* and two *rows*

The number of rows is incorrect. Should be:

```
columns: 5
rows: 5
```

Specify preferred widths and heights as percentages or units. I'm using units below because it is easier to relate to your 4:1 and 2:3 proportions:

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    columns: 5
    rows: 5                        // was 2

    Rectangle {
        Layout.column: 0
        Layout.columnSpan: 4
        Layout.row: 0
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.preferredWidth: 4   // 4 of 5 cols
        Layout.preferredHeight: 2  // 2 of 5 rows
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.column: 4
        Layout.columnSpan: 1
        Layout.row: 0
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.preferredWidth: 1   // 1 of 5 cols
        Layout.preferredHeight: 2  // 2 of 5 rows
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        color: "green"
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.column: 0
        Layout.columnSpan: 5
        Layout.row: 2
        Layout.rowSpan: 3
        Layout.preferredHeight: 3  // 3 of 5 rows
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot showing expected proportions]

Below is minimal code using percentages to achieve the same result:

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 2

    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 80
        Layout.preferredHeight: 40
        color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 20
        Layout.preferredHeight: 40

        color: "green"
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        Layout.preferredHeight: 60

        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kao recommended binding to the columnSpan and rowSpan. This works because they are unit proportions.

If all elements on a row have `Layout.fillWidth` set `true`, their preferred widths are used to determine their proportional width. Binding an element's `preferredWidth` to its `columnspan` establishes a ratio that the GridLayout uses to compute the element's width: a span of 4 in a grid with 5 columns results in the element taking up 80% of the total width of the grid. The same goes for elements in a column.

This solution uses a Qt 5.15 inline component:

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 5
    rows: 5

    component ProportionalRect: Rectangle {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: Layout.rowSpan
    }

    ProportionalRect {
        Layout.columnSpan: 4
        Layout.rowSpan: 2

        color: "red"
    }

    ProportionalRect {
        Layout.columnSpan: 1
        Layout.rowSpan: 2

        color: "green"
    }

    ProportionalRect {
        Layout.columnSpan: 5
        Layout.rowSpan: 3

        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to leave any empty spaces in grid, you can make width and height proportional to spans by binding preferred sizes to spans.

```
Layout.fillWidth: true
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.preferredWidth: Layout.columnSpan
Layout.preferredHeight: Layout.rowSpan
```