# QML Gridlayout Problems

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout

I wish to make a prototype screen layout using QML and a GridLayout. I cannot get it to work. I have followed many previous examples here on Stackoverflow but nothing works satisfactorily and its clear I do not understand QML layouts and need some help. (DevEnv: Centos 7.5, Qt 5.11/QtCreator 4.7.1)

I wish to achieve this screen layout (ignore the colours)

[image: Desired Layout]

**Example 1**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    visibility: "Maximized"
    title: 'Title'

    GridLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        rows: 8
        columns: 12

        Rectangle {
            id: view_A
            color: "lightgreen"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 11
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_A" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_B
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 5
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_B"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_C
            color: "blue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 6
            Text { text: "view_C" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_D
            color: "blueviolet"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 5
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 10
            Text { text: "view_D" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_E
            color: "lightblue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 3
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_E" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_F
            color: "darkorange"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 6
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 4
            Text { text: "view_F" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_G
            color: "seagreen"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.row: 7
            Layout.column: 10
            Text { text: "view_G" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_H
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.rowSpan: 8
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 12
            Text { text: "view_H" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution comes close, however, the grid elements are not the sizes I specified. For example the top element id: view_A is far taller than desired, as is the width of id: view_H.
(Screenshot of results of Example 1 QML code execution )

[image: Failed Element Sizes Example 1]

**Example 2:**

I then tried the solution provided here ([How can I create a QML GridLayout with items of proportionate sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027727/how-can-i-create-a-qml-gridlayout-with-items-of-proportionate-sizes)). 
This has come as close as I can get but there are ugly spaces between some elements.

```
// QML Code Example 2

import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    visibility: "Maximized"
    title: 'Title'

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rowSpacing: 0
        columnSpacing: 0

        rows: 8
        columns: 12

        property double colMultiplier: grid.width / grid.columns
        property double rowMultiplier: grid.height / grid.rows;
        function getElementHeight(element) {
            return element.Layout.rowSpan * rowMultiplier
        }
        function getElementWidth(element) {
            return element.Layout.columnSpan * colMultiplier
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_A
            color: "lightgreen"
            Layout.columnSpan: 11
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_A" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_B
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.columnSpan: 5
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_B"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_C
            color: "blue"
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 6
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_C" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_D
            color: "blueviolet"
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 5
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 10
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_D" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_E
            color: "lightblue"
            Layout.columnSpan: 3
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_E" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_F
            color: "darkorange"
            Layout.columnSpan: 6
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 4
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_F" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_G
            color: "seagreen"
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.row: 7
            Layout.column: 10
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_G" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_H
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.rowSpan: 8
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 12
            Layout.preferredHeight: grid.getElementHeight(this)
            Layout.preferredWidth:  grid.getElementWidth(this)
            Text { text: "view_H" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example 2 Failure]

So as can be seen in the resultant screenshot that ther are spaces between some elements that look terrible.

So, if there are any QML experts that can help solve this issue I would really like to hear from you.

kind regards ...

Comment: have you tried nested horiz and vert containers instead of trying to force a grid to give you the aspect ratios you want?

Comment: Yes, I tried for a full day using RowLayouts and ColumnLayouts but could not get them to work in any logical fashion so I gave up on them completely and hoped that the GridLayout would be somewhat easier ...

Comment: Actually, I mean `QVBoxLayout` and `QHBoxLayout`.  The top layout, in your example, would QHBoxLayout and would contain two items: a QVBoxLayout (we'll call "left" here) and the `view_H` widget.  Then the "left" vbox layout would contain the `view_A` widget followed by a new QVBoxLayout, in which would go two VBoxes...  you keep dividing til you win!

Answer (score 1):

You can add Layout.preferedWidth and Layout.preferedHeight to fix this

```
GridLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        rows: 8
        columns: 12

        Rectangle {
            id: view_A
            color: "lightgreen"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 11
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth: 11
            Layout.preferredHeight: 1
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_A" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_B
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 5
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.preferredWidth: 5
            Layout.preferredHeight: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_B"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_C
            color: "blue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.preferredWidth: 4
            Layout.preferredHeight: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 6
            Text { text: "view_C" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_D
            color: "blueviolet"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 5
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            Layout.preferredHeight: 5
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 10
            Text { text: "view_D" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_E
            color: "lightblue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 3
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.preferredWidth: 3
            Layout.preferredHeight: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 1
            Text { text: "view_E" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_F
            color: "darkorange"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 6
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.preferredWidth: 6
            Layout.preferredHeight: 4
            Layout.row: 5
            Layout.column: 4
            Text { text: "view_F" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_G
            color: "seagreen"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            Layout.preferredHeight: 2
            Layout.row: 7
            Layout.column: 10
            Text { text: "view_G" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: view_H
            color: "yellow"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.rowSpan: 8
            Layout.preferredWidth: 1
            Layout.preferredHeight: 8
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 12
            Text { text: "view_H" ; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        }
    }
```

Result :

[image]